# cannot remove conda package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I seem to be unable to uninstall a package.

when I run `conda remove geopandas` I get:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - geopandas
```

If I then run `conda info geopandas` I get a list of 10 versions of geopandas looking like `geopandas 0.4.0 py37_1`, `geopandas 0.4.1 py_0`, etc. Are these installed on my system? How do I remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `conda info` command examines packages on the conda repository. It's not what you're looking for.

You can see what packages are installed in your anaconda distribution with the command `conda list`. You can look for only geopandas through a command like `conda list | grep geopandas`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. If the packages were pip installed `conda remove` won't work. In that case, you'll have to do `pip uninstall geopandas`. If you run `conda list geopandas` and the channel says `pypi`, then they were pip installed.